# my css and sass classes are shown inside <style>tags in <head> while I was coding in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was making react components and everything was good until I see that my sass classes are shown in my result

when I view the page source every thing is ok and `<body>` contains my code inside the root element ,but when I inspect elements there are `<style>` tags with sass classes inside `<head>` also my console has no errors.
I can solve this issue using `style{display:none;}` but I want to know the reason why this issue happens.

inspect and my result are in this picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when you style your application with `.css` or `.sass` files, like the initial ones that come with `create-react-app (index.css)`. If you want to style your app and don't want that to show, create `.js` files and put your css inside, using [inline style](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), for example.

Example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: what if I had lots of sass files should I write my sass code in .js files or not???

Comment: You can try other approaches such as: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet... But as react team says *"Following this rule often makes CSS preprocessors less useful, as features like `mixins` and `nesting` are replaced by `component composition`. You can, however, integrate a CSS preprocessor if you find it valuable."*